# SecureRandom number should be 12 numbers, but getting 17

Tags: java

I have the following code.

```
private String getEsignConfirmNum() {
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    String esignConfirmNum = "";
    while (esignConfirmNum.length() < 12) {
        int randomNumber = secureRandom.nextInt(1000000);
        esignConfirmNum += randomNumber;
    }
    return esignConfirmNum;

}

"esignConfirmationNum":"21189530230267936"
```

but, in my req to the API, it came back as 17 numbers.... why? is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Just use, _secureRandom.nextLong(100_000_000_000L, 1_000_000_000_000L)_.

Answer (score 9):

esignConfirmNum is a string. When you call `esignConfirmNum += randomNumber`, that `+` means **string concatenate**.

So let's simulate a loop:

1. esignConfirmNum is `""` which is definitely a length below 12, so, enter the loop.
2. Random number generated is 856123.
3. `esignConfirmNum` is now `"856123"` which has a length below 12, so, enter again.
4. Random number generated is '1'. Wow, that's low. Lucky perhaps?
5. `esignConfirmNum` is now `"8561231"`. **Not `"856124"`** - that plus means string concat, not mathematical addition, remember. That's still a length below 12, so, loop.
6. We generate 9999 as random number. `esignConfirmNum` is now `"85612319999"`. Length 11, so loop again.
7. We generate 123456. `esignConfirmNum` is now `"85612319999123456"` so the loop stops, and esignConfirmationNum is now 17 characters long.

So, your code does exactly what you told it to, it works fine. Except, you are asking questions about it - perhaps you are confused or possibly (guessing here, your question isn't very clearly written) you want some code that produces a uniformly distributed random number that has precisely 12 digits in it.

Then.. just write that.

The lowest 'legal' number is `1000 0000 0000`. The highest 'legal' number is `9999 9999 9999`. That's a total 'range' of `9000 0000 0000` different possible numbers in the universe of allowed numbers you wish to generate; you want one of those, uniformly randomly decided (as in, any number as as likely as any other, that is what 'uniform random' means). So, generate a random number between 0 inclusive and `9000 0000 0000` exclusive, then add `1000 0000 0000` to it. Use `long`, because ints don't go beyond `2^31-1` which is about 10 digits; not enough. longs go up to 18 or so, more than enough for your needs:

```
long rnd = secureRandom.nextLong(8999_9999_9999L) + 1000_0000_0000L;
```

Comment: `nextLong` has an overload for sampling from a range: `secureRandom.nextLong(100_000_000_000L, 1_000_000_000_000L)`

Comment: ... which does that calculation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually all you have to do is to cut required numbers from the generated string.

```java
public static String getEsignConfirmNum(int length) {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(2 * length);

    while (buf.length() < length) {
        buf.append(random.nextInt(1_000_000));
    }

    return buf.substring(0, length);
}
```

But, on the other side all you need just convert the number to the `String` and add missing `0` as a prefix.

```java
public static String getEsignConfirmNum(int bound) {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    int width = String.valueOf(bound).length();
    int num = random.nextInt(bound);
    return String.format("%0" + width + 'd', num);
}
```

Another way is just generate required amount of one-digit numbers:

```java
public static String getEsignConfirmNum(int length) {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        buf.append(random.nextInt(10));

    return buf.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... is there a better way to handle this? ..."*

I recommend just looping 12 times, and append a *String* value.

```java
String string = "";
for (int count = 0; count < 12; count++)
    string += secureRandom.nextInt(10);
long value = Long.parseLong(string);
```

Here are some example outputs,

```
431525756892
909223717286
806345775078
```